# Mozilla: How to fake a response with nsITraceableChannel

Tags: proxy, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am developing a proxy using `nsITraceableChannel` (`addon-proxy` on npm). I am able to modify incoming responses, but how do I *fake* one?

Let's say that if the URL contains `hello.html`, I want to return `hello world` as a response. I can't redirect to a different page, because it would not be transparent to the client and would mess with same-origin stuff.

For now I let the request go to the server and just completely rewrite the incoming response (see Noitidart's snippet, which can be found online in many variants). This is far from optimal for my specific use case:

- I send a request and wait for the server anyway, even though the data is available locally.
- I cannot change headers such as content-type and status code from the actual value.

Is there a way to feed a complete response to the underlying listener without actually issuing one on the network?

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible.

This gist shows how to just get a copy of it: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/d0b08629ee2804538ad9 - you can copy and paste this to scratchpad, hit run, and see it in action.

Notice on line 44, it sets `this.responseBody = this.receivedChunks.join('');`

So basically you would set `this.responseBody` to whatever you want

Heres the code from the gist:

```
var {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, results: Cr, Constructor: CC, utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var BinaryInputStream = CC('@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1', 'nsIBinaryInputStream', 'setInputStream');
var BinaryOutputStream = CC('@mozilla.org/binaryoutputstream;1', 'nsIBinaryOutputStream', 'setOutputStream');
var StorageStream = CC('@mozilla.org/storagestream;1', 'nsIStorageStream', 'init');

function TracingListener() {
    this.receivedChunks = []; // array for incoming data. holds chunks as they come, onStopRequest we join these junks to get the full source
    this.responseBody; // we'll set this to the 
    this.responseStatusCode;

    this.deferredDone = {
        promise: null,
        resolve: null,
        reject: null
    };
    this.deferredDone.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject;
    }.bind(this.deferredDone));
    Object.freeze(this.deferredDone);
    this.promiseDone = this.deferredDone.promise;
}
TracingListener.prototype = {
    onDataAvailable: function(aRequest, aContext, aInputStream, aOffset, aCount) {
        var iStream = new BinaryInputStream(aInputStream) // binaryaInputStream
        var sStream = new StorageStream(8192, aCount); // storageStream // not sure why its 8192 but thats how eveyrone is doing it, we should ask why
        var oStream = new BinaryOutputStream(sStream.getOutputStream(0)); // binaryOutputStream

        // Copy received data as they come.
        var data = iStream.readBytes(aCount);
        this.receivedChunks.push(data);

        oStream.writeBytes(data, aCount);

        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(aRequest, aContext, sStream.newInputStream(0), aOffset, aCount);
    },
    onStartRequest: function(aRequest, aContext) {
        this.originalListener.onStartRequest(aRequest, aContext);
    },
    onStopRequest: function(aRequest, aContext, aStatusCode) {
        this.responseBody = this.receivedChunks.join('');
        delete this.receivedChunks;
        this.responseStatus = aStatusCode;
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(aRequest, aContext, aStatusCode);

        this.deferredDone.resolve();
    },
    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIStreamListener) || aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports)) {
            return this;
        }
        throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
};

var httpResponseObserver = {
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
        var newListener = new TracingListener();
        aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
        newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
        /////// END - DO NOT EDIT
        newListener.promiseDone.then(
            function() {
                // no error happened
                console.log('yay response done:', newListener.responseBody);
            },
            function(aReason) {
                // promise was rejected, right now i didnt set up rejection, but i should listen to on abort or bade status code then reject maybe
            }
        ).catch(
            function(aCatch) {
                console.error('something went wrong, a typo by dev probably:', aCatch);
            }
        );
    }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(httpResponseObserver, 'http-on-examine-response', false);
// Services.obs.removeObserver(httpResponseObserver, 'http-on-examine-response'); // call this when you dont want to listen anymore
```

Comment: This is already what I am doing (see https://github.com/BruceBerry/addon-proxy/blob/master/proxy.js) and there are countless examples of this out there. Unlike the normal case where you want to modify a real response from a server, here I want to return a completely fake response, so #1 and #2 apply: with your code you are sending a request on the network for no reason, you are waiting on the response to return data even though the data is already available locally, and most importantly, you cannot change the response status code, content-type and other values.

Comment: @BruceBerry I'm certain it is not sending another request. It is making a copy of a request. If yo uwant to fake a response status code I'm not sure how to do that. What I think you should do, is something like when you go to a a page that shows a problem loading page, you see how they redirect that to another page but the url does not change? Look into how they do that and share please. What I do know is that the new url is seen in the `nsiWebNavigation` like - `win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation).document.documentURI;`

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks. My requirement is not to avoid making a second request (as you said, it doesn't), but to avoid the first one too! Once the channel recognizes that this request can actually be served locally, it should not send any data over the network and wait for the response.

Comment: @BruceBerry here is info on how docUri is different but document.location is original - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=13296131#p13296131